# How to creat direction map app

Tags: javascript, android, html

am thinking of creating an app as a project for my app development class, which gives direction to the school campus building from the present location. Is that a possible, if so can anyone suggest some advice what should i look into.
thank you

Comment: How old is your device? The new maps API does not work well on versions less than Honeycomb. You might also want to consider OSM droid. I used that for a project once and it worked very well.

Comment: am using nexus 5.. but since i will try to make it for school. try to cover as much device as possible

Answer (score 1):

you will depend on `Google API` and here some links will help you :

```
Google Map API :
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/  and here good example on how to get your location and draw markers on map

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

and you will need `Google Direction API`  to get the direction from place to another with more functionality you can use in API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

good example on `Google Direction API` :

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

and any related good tutorial i will edit my answer with it

hope it helpful for you and feed me back in any thing not obvious for you

Comment: thank you for the link .. i will surly update on it.

Answer (score 0):

> if so can anyone suggest some advice what should i look into

The main advice i will give you is to begin your reading with [official doc Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) which is a complete tuto. Follow it step by step in order to be canalised, because there is many docs in the web, and some of them talk about API v1 of `Google Map` which is now deprecated.

Otherwise, you will be lost ;)